# "With eyes wide open" or "with the eyes wide open"?

Tags: definite-article

Consider the following sentence:

> This verb literally means "to look fixedly at something or someone
> **with eyes** wide open" and it suggests being so attentive to or
> mesmerized/shocked by what you see that you couldn't look away.

I'm wondering, should it be "with **the** eyes wide open" or is there a nuanced difference between using and leaving out "the" after "with" in similar phrases?

Comment: Definitely not ***the** [eyes]* in any remotely "normal" context. But dictionary definitions *aren't* "normal contexts", so it's not out of place in your first sentence above, which is presented as a definition. In other contexts though, if you want to include a determiner it would be perfectly idiomatic to say *with **his/her** eyes wide open*.

Comment: There is another meaning of **with eyes wide open** in the context of **going into a situation with eyes wide open** Which means going into the situation knowing full well the circumstances and problems it you could face.

Comment: This might also answer your question: [Is it not correct to say "I have the brown eyes" instead of "I have brown eyes", and why?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/192156/9161)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no significance in the inclusion/omission of *the*. Since *you* is used later in the sentence, the writer could also have put *with your eyes wide open.*